# REST API naming convention for multiple resources

Tags: node.js, rest, naming-conventions

I'm working on a REST API and I'm wondering what the naming convention should be for an endpoint that returns two different types of objects. In this contrived example, I've got a call to get a movie (by ID), and another to get the actors associated with a particular movie.

```
this.app.get('/movies/:id', moviesCtrl.getMovie);
this.app.get('/movies/:id/actors', moviesCtrl.getMovieActors);
```

My question is, what should be the path for a call that returns both the movie and the actors (i.e., the JSON for the movie but also appends an array of the list of actors)?

```
this.app.get('/movie-actors/:id', moviesCtrl.getMovieWithActors);
```

Comment: if I understood you correctly you want to have list of all movies with actors inside. If yes then in /movie-actors/:id which id is it?

Comment: @Mara the ID is the movie. All the associated actors would be linked to the movie in a 3rd table (e.g., movie_actors). The endpoint movie-actors returns one movie with all the actors.

Comment: then /movies/:id/actors is the best option for this purpose

Comment: @Mara  thx. So then I guess the actors alone would be /actors/movie/:id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I get full picture. So I would go with the next names:

1. Movies without actors: `/movies/:id`
2. Movies with actors: `/actors/movies/:movieId` or `movies_with_actors/:movieId`
3. Only actors: `/movies/:id/actors`

Or you can combine 1st and 2nd endpoints and create boolean parameter `/movies/:id?actors=true` and `/movies/:id?actors=false`

But it is just a taste preference. The main idea: path should be meaningful. And the main rule is `GET /movies - get all` `Get /movies/:id - get one`